# Footer not animating height on scrolling bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

When I scroll down 50px to bottom I want the footer to fill the whole window. I tried to animate its height but not working.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
...
</div>

<footer>
    <div id="sitemap">Sitemap</div>
    <div id="about">About Us</div>
    <div id="contact">Contact Us</div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
* { margin:0; padding:0;}
#main { height:1400px;}
footer { background:#333; color:#FAFAFA; border-top:5px solid #000; width:100%;  height:50px; }
footer > div { display:inline-block; height:auto;}
#sitemap { width:25%;}
#about { width:35%;}
```

jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
    docH = $(document).height(),
    winH = $(this).height();

if(scrollTop + winH >= docH-50){
    $('footer').stop().animate({height:'100%'},'slow');
}else{
    $('footer').stop().animate({height:'50px'},'slow');
}
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you put you code in fiddle ?

Comment: Where is that 50px you mean? is that the 50px I set in CSS? I thought jquery put its styling as style attribute so it overruled the one I set in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you say height: '100%' it is saying 100% of 50px...

try adding

```
footer { max-height: 100%; }
```

in your css

it should resolve your issue